# Monitoring variable change done by jQuery inside component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular9, google-blockly

I know this isn't optimal, but I have regular javascript code changing a variable that is property in my component.

The reason for this is that I have dynamic javascript (that comes from Google Blockly) being run (`eval`) in my component.

Here's the component template:

```
<input #textInput
   [attr.max-value]="maxValue"
   type="number"
   style="width: 495px;"
   (change)="onChange($event)"
   [id]="key"
   class="form-control"
   [disabled]="disabled"
   value="{{value}}" />
```

And the component code:

```
export class NumberStepComponent extends BaseStepComponent {
    /** number-step ctor */
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    @ViewChild("textInput") textInput: ElementRef;

    private _maxValue: string;
    get maxValue(): string {
        return this._maxValue;
    }

    set maxValue(val: string) {
        this._maxValue = val;
        console.log("Changed ** : " + val);
    }

}
```

When I change `maxValue` from Angular, I do get the setter code triggered. But when jQuery does it, that setter isn't triggered.

ie:

```
var code = `$('#ID').attr('max-value', "5")`;
eval(code);
```

I've tried executing the code "in the zone" thinking this would keep Angular up to date:

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    var code = `$('#ID').attr('max-value', "5")`;
    eval(code);
});
```

Doesn't trigger the setter either. Any ways to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `$('#ID').attr('max-value', "5")`, since the value is binded (so handled by Angular).

If you want to change the value, update the model (this.maxValue = '5'), not the view. Angular will update the view for you.

Comment: The problem is that the javascript is dynamic. I can't write `this.maxValue`, my application doesn't know what that is.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Can you explain how is the jQuery triggered then ? The side note is you shouldn't need to use jQuery, so let's see how you could do without using jQuery and using Angular mechanisms...

Comment: Code is generated by Blockly: https://developers.google.com/blockly - a visual programming widget that allows producing the resulting code, JS in this case. I don't think it can produce typescript that Angular can then run.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what you can/cannot do but you can try to add a MutationObserver. For example :

```
const node = document.querySelector('.some-element') // or this.textInput.nativeElement;

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => console.log(mutation));
});

observer.observe(node, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
});
```